# Product of digit runs

Tags: code-golf, number

We seem to quite like digit runs lately, so here's a fairly simple challenge.

Given a positive integer, split it into it's digit runs, and return the product.

For example:

`11122333` would become `111, 22, 333`, the product of which is `813186`

Input may be taken as an integer, string, or list/array of digits/characters. Your entry must work for any number within it's representable range. I have tested this for 32-bit integers (2^32-1 max value) and the largest possible result I have found is `1099999989` from `1199999999`, which is also within the 32-bit integer range. I have yet to find a number who's output is larger than the input.

For the purposes of this challenge, runs of length 1 are not counted.

If there is only 1 run, return the run. If there are no runs, do anything (undefined behaviour)

Standard I/O rules apply, output can be given as an integer or string.

### Testcases

```
11122333 -> 813186
1112333 -> 36963
1122855098 -> 13310
98776543 -> 77
1000000 -> 0
123456789 -> undefined
1 -> undefined
99445662 -> 287496
1199999999 -> 1099999989
999999999 -> 999999999
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: "For the purposes of this challenge, runs of length 1 are not counted." This seems completely arbitrary.

Comment: can the input begin with a 0?

Comment: @Fatalize I won't argue with that, was mostly just a slight de-trivialization as otherwise I could see some languages simply doing `[builtin to split into runs][builtin to get product of entire stack]`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista No, an integer can't logically have leading zeroes.

Comment: @Mayube Adding arbitrary constraints to make a trivial challenge barely less trivial does not seem like a desirable thing to do to me.

Comment: Why are no runs undefined?  I'm not  really complaining, I don't think it matters much, but the product of the empty set is 1 in pretty much any definition of product.

Comment: @WheatWizard I prefer to leave "invalid" inputs as either undefined, or remove them completely, I like undefined behaviour for cases like this as it sometimes allows answers to have a lot more flexibility. (Although admittedly perhaps not so much in this particular case)

Comment: If the output was required to be undefined I would have had to increase my code by nearly an additional ⅔ `{/(.)$0/??[*] .comb(/(.)$0+/)!!Mu}` . Which would also make the code less clear.

Comment: Proof that the output never exceeds the input: it suffices to show that if two positive integers `A` and `B` are concatenated to form the integer `C`, then `A*B<C`. But if `B` has `d` digits, then `B<10^d`, and so `C = A*10^d + B ≥ A*10^d > A*B`.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills the output being undefined means your code can output anything you want, even exit with error

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Precisely. Many languages have a value which is referred to as being undefined. If there had to be a different result, it would take the place of the `Mu`; so a penalty of 11 bytes plus whatever it takes to encode the result.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>63</s> 55 bytes

Since no one has done Haskell yet here's my take on it.  Takes a string as input (of course).

```hs
import Data.List
f s=product[read x|x@(_:_:_)<-group s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrTaHYtqAoP6U0uSS6KDUxRaGipsJBI94KCDVtdNOL8ksLFIpj/@cmZuYB1WXmlaikaRRn5JcrGBoaGhkZGWv@BwA)

This code almost looks as if it is not golfed, but I cannot find anyway to make it shorter.

Comment: Your code fails on the test case `f "1"`.  Expected output is undefined

Comment: @maple_shaft undefined does not mean they literally want `undefined` as the output, only that the behavior of the program is undefined.  `1` is valid output for `"1"`.

Comment: You can check the length condition in the pattern match, like this: `x@(_:_:_)<-`, and the numeric type of `product` is enough for the defaulting rule to apply, so you don't need the type annotation.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Takes input as a string, outputs an integer or `1` for "undefined".

```
ò¦ fa_Ã×
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8qYgZmFfw9c=&input=IjExMTIzMzMi)

- 2 bytes saved thanks to [ETH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

Comment: Does this multiply by 10 or something?

Comment: Incorrect output for `1112333`, outputs `73926` when it should output `36963`

Comment: @Mayube: Fixed now.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer; I'd missed the rule about ignoring runs of length 1.

Comment: I found a couple ways of dealing with that rule that only amount to 8 bytes: `ò¦ fa_Ã×` or `ò¦ f>9 ×`

Comment: @ETHproductions: D'oh! `f>9` should have been obvious. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, @ETHproductions, `f>9` won't work as it will also remove runs of `0`s.

Comment: `ò¦` is such a cool trick.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

```
γ9ÝKP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3GbLw3O9A/7/t7QwNzczNTEGAA)

If we don't need to ignore runs of length one, 2 bytes:

```
γP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OaA//8tLczNzUxNjAE)

Comment: Save a byte by using `9Ý` instead of `žhS`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Ah! I knew there was a way to do it in 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>46</s> <s>45</s> <s>38</s> 35 bytes

Takes input as a string, outputs an integer or throws an error for "undefined".

```js
s=>eval(s.match(/(.)\1+/g).join`*`)
```

- 7 bytes saved thanks to [Herman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70894/herman-lauenstein).
- 3 bytes saved thanks to [Craig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68610/craig-ayre).

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=
s=>eval(s.match(/(.)\1+/g).join`*`)
)(i.value="11122333");oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Comment: -9 bytes: `s=>s.replace(/(.)\1+/g,m=>n*=m,n=1)&&n` (I haven't tested it yet)

Comment: Seems to do the job, thanks, @HermanLauenstein :) Was playing around to see if I could get it shorter using `+` instead of  `*` but hadn't got there yet.

Comment: Could you use `eval` to save a few bytes? `s=>eval(s.match(/(.)\1+/g).join\`*\`)` - throws an error if no runs

Comment: Nice one, @CraigAyre. I was stupidly trying to see if I could save bytes by passing the `replace` through `eval`! Given the state of my golfing the past couple of days, it's a very good thing I have a holiday coming up tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ŒgḊÐfḌP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPSHO7oOT0h7uKMn4P///9GGOgoQZARGxhAUCwA)

-1 thanks to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun).

Comment: [7 bytes?](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPSHO7oOT0h7uKMn4P///9GGOgoQZARGxhAUCwA)

Comment: @LeakyNun Ooh clever trick...

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 25 bytes

24 bytes + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/(.)\1+/$.*=$&/eg;$_=$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpbCsIwFAX/7yqubRAfmFebtCHk010USi1BhFiCieuP9TU/MxxO9I@gSr2Jq/EUS2I7uh/EkRF6cGTL/NWS0RFaLEKN52W6BJ/w/gz5FoPH7FPGeUo@ARmROqyGpbJAKDrktgghpGyaBt7xtZS9Utz0YPqu06pdN/4BjGlbpbVcT@YH/MO8AA)

Quite straight forward: `(.)\1+` matches the runs of more than one digit, and `$.*=$&` uses `$.` as accumulator for the multiplications (because its initial value is 1 and not 0). Finally, `$_` is set to `$.` and implicitly printed thanks to `-p` flag.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
{[*] .comb(/(.)$0+/)}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##VY/NTsMwEITvfoo9RDShJY3jxLEVFbhy50YRKokrBaVJlB8EqsKLcePFwm5qCvjkmf1mx25MW8pp6Ay8Sj9L2eEdLrI6N7CZjg@Xj@Bn9eHZXbu@5wTLtTdOCNz2puthA2VRmc71vj4ttM2RQHVX9SmjlffIpawpdxUs51DK9nVr81fX4DyB6xRVM/Qrx7w1JutNfuPBkQFgjdOabiipiB5kQS/FYbGH3OyxPYdzbk7hqPvJrX5nK/Bf6qJyF1S68BAcwZT4wFOm2XWYmtfDB5wgvNg9RLNx4pyHoRCCpooLriQjyzpCaikYISqOA63I40LwgGmVJDKOZipJGA/mQypgGI9imShNcqjsnxj/L7WOkJIhuaFKIk3N2p65KDjdlWb6r38W3w)

This returns `1` if there is no *“digit runs”* as that is the base case for multiplication.

The only change to allow one digit runs is to replace `$0+` with `$0*` in the regular expression.

### Expanded:

```perl6
{            # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [*]        # reduce the following using &infix:<*>

    .comb(   # pull out substrings that match the following
             # (implicit method call on ｢$_｣)

      /
        (.)  # any digit (character)
        $0+  # at least one more of that digit
      /
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>95</s> 79 bytes

-2 thanks to @LeakyNum

```python
l='0'
p=1
for c in input()+' ':a=c in l;p*=int(l)**(len(l)>1>a);l=l*a+c
print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LDsIgEEXX8hWTbuhjU@gLanCnWzf@QIOYNiEtoTTq11cg6mQW5947D/N24zLTXS53BQKSJNm1wCVGRhD0WCxImGbfZnNpVmDA/SCipY8mF9PsUp3learV7OFETkN21ELnQyGRsT4Gs/ubyNl3jw7PcdIKbnZTXhzUS0kIf5F6SWUcnK@Xs7WL9aEZ1nXHhBBKq6rCKOKPKGVNU3LmBWdd1zZ19MtYgWhVN23HeOAwxGuvWxqX@bei/@cP)

Comment: `[1,int(l)][len(l)>1]` is equivalent to `int(l)**(len(l)>1)`

Comment: Would `l=''` instead of `l='0'` work?

Comment: no, the `int(l)` would throw an error if the string was empty

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 47 bytes

```
(.)\1+
$*_ 
T`d
{`(?<=^(_+) _*)_
$1
}`^_+ _
_
_
```

This is slow on the larger test cases.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ08zxlCbS0UrXoErJCGFqzpBw97GNk4jXltTIV5LM55LxZCrNiEuXlshngsI//83NDQysjA1NbC0AAA)

#### Explanation

```
(.)\1+
$*_
```

First, replace each run of 2 or more of the same digit with that many `_`s, followed by a space for separation.

```
T`d
```

Then remove all remaining digits.

```
{`(?<=^(_+) _*)_
$1
}`^_+ _
_
```

Next, run these two stages in a loop. The first replaces every `_` in the second run with the entire first run, effectively multiplying them. The second stage deletes the first run.

```
_
```

Finally, output the number `_`s.

Comment: You can get this to [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ08zxlCbS0UrXoErJCGFSzshxj1ew95WT0tBI15bU7NGIV5bhUvFkCv@/39LC3NzM1MTYwA) by using the multiplication stage from [Retinas wiki](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/Tutorial:-Unary-arithmetic#multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>93</s> 89 bytes

There must be some more golfing to be done here...

```c
z,r;f(char*d){for(z=0;r=*d++;z=r/10?z?z*r:r:z)for(r-=48;r%10==*d-48;r=r*10+*d++-48);d=z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLboMwEEX3@QqEFAlDUP3Cj1hufqSbCIeURUk0ajeO8u0Uk6C4Mp3VeO49vva09bltx9HvwHRF@3mE0qFbd4HCW2zAlq6qjLfwRvDBH3wJe9h7FHSoLVcGtgTbyVWH3kJJcBWQ6YiMs97cx69jPxRoc9tkU12hH767IieEUMoYy@r3TBFGlMi27mPId5GWI2QS6MkwoQX7i6wTlKqmwVoFiDBGcAwtYsJpJaVo@Bwl5QtZ5mkQniv444THNHVTxhshlQ7@n8Gdun44uYhb9JT8j0i/oPl0h6ABoEpyHW140Vb2pZ817ws/@umd0dIWx0pixL4OUWpM3sdf)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
Times@@FromDigits/@Select[Split@IntegerDigits@#,Length@#>1&]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval('*'.join(zip(*re.findall(r'((.)\2+)',n))[0]))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvRDoIgGEav8yn@O8DIKYqKW72IekFLFw2BoWurl6fNaJ2r7@zsc6/tbg0L83kIWi7XmwTTTU@pMUpR9rDK4LdyOPVTNitzk1pjjzDOyMCOBFFDSJ@PhCRqcdZv4KcwWw8rKAN9ckBFUTBWliWiUf6bsZbzXLS7irZpal7Flu98g6gqXtcsnkQktp@NHTivzAYrBXS6IAozXkn4AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 62 bytes

prints 1 if no run is found

```php
preg_match_all('#(.)\1+#',$argn,$t);echo array_product($t[0]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lkliUnmerZGhoZGRhampgaaFk/b@gKDU9PjexJDkjPjEnR0NdWUNPM8ZQW1ldB6xaR6VE0zo1OSNfIbGoKLEyvqAoP6U0uURDpSTaIFbT@v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 41 bytes

```rb
p eval gets.scan(/(.)\1+/).map(&:join)*?*
```

Takes input from stdin, scans it for runs of length > 1, joins them on `"*"`, evaluates and prints.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 18 Bytes

```
qe`{0=1>},{:*i}%:*
```

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qe%60%7B0%3D1%3E%7D%2C%7B%3A*i%7D%25%3A*&input=11122333)

```
q           e# read string - '1112333'
e`          e# convert string to RLE - [[3,'1'],[1,'2'],[3,'3']]
{0=1>},     e# filter out runs of length one - [[3,'1'],[3,'3']]
{:*i}%      e# convert sub-arrays to runs - [111,333]
:*          e# multiply array elements - 36963
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 151 bytes

```
[ { } { } ] dip
[ 48 - 2dup swap in? [ suffix ] [ [ suffix ] dip 1array ] if ] each
suffix rest [ 0 swap [ swap 10 * + ] each ] map product
```

Getting a better grip on this language! Still don't think I'm using enough combinators...